# C, pre and post increment, different answers in different programs

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

testing some code  when studying C language,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define hypotenusa(x, y)  sqrt((x) * (x) + (y) * (y))

int main(void) {
    int a, x;
    x = 2;
    a = hypotenusa(++x, ++x);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

And I am getting the answer

- `6` in one program(dosbox gcc compiler)
- `7` in codelight gcc compiler and
- `8` on codeChef online compiler

can anyone explain this behaviour? 
my logic says it should be `6` (`sqrt(42)`) but...

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060968/using-the-post-increment-in-function-arguments and many other questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't immediately realize that it was not a function call. However, it does not change the essence of the issue.

Comment: Read the info page before asking! This is one of the "do not ask" questions.

Comment: @AnT: why not dup-hammer then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After the macro replacement

```
a = hypotenusa(++x, ++x);
```

becomes:

```
a = sqrt((++x) * (++x) + (++x) * (++x));
```

As you can see `x` is modified multiple times without any intervening sequence point(s). See [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: It worth noting, that converting it to a function call won't solve the problem, as the order of operands evaluation is not defined too..

Answer (score 2):

`hypotenusa(++x, ++x)` is undefined behavior.
It is up to the compiler which of the parameters gets incremented (and pushed) first - after the macro expansion, there are a total of four instances, and the sequence is not defined.

You should never increment the same variable multiple times in the same statement, to avoid this kind of issues. Using a variable twice in a macro can hide this error and make it really nasty.

Comment: `hypotenusa` is a macro, not a function call, and there is nothing wrong with incrementing a variable during a function call, so long as you increment it ONLY ONCE.  Trouble happens when you increment the same variable multiple times.

Comment: @abelenky , the macro expands to a function call. But I have adjusted the text to be more precise.

Comment: Could you clarify the first paragraph. It suggest that the undefined behavior will result in one of the two possible outcomes, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of your macro is undefined, meaning *any* result is possible.

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.5 Expressions**
> ...
> 2     If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
>       on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
> object,
>       the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the
> subexpressions
>       of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side
> effect occurs in any
>       of the orderings.<sup>84)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 84) This paragraph renders undefined statement expressions such as
>
> ```
>     i = ++i + 1;
>     a[i++] = i;
> ```
>
> while allowing
>
> ```
>     i = i + 1;
>     a[i] = i;
> ```

Basically, if you modify the value of an object more than once in an expression, or both modify an object and use its value in a computation in an expression, the result will not be well-defined unless there is a *sequence point* in between those operations.  With a few exceptions, C does not force left-to-right evaluation of expressions or function parameter evaluations, nor does it mandate that the side effect of `++` or `--` be applied immediately after evaluation.  Thus, the result of an expression like `x++ * x++` will vary from platform to platform, program to program, or even potentially from run to run (although I've never seen that in practice).

For example, given the expression `y = x++ * x++`, the following evaluation sequence is possible:

```
t0 <- x        // right hand x++, t0 == 2
t1 <- x        // left hand x++, t1 == 2
y <- t0 * t1   // y = 2 * 2 == 4
x <- x + 1     // x == 3
x <- x + 1     // x == 4
```

which doesn't give you the result you expect if you assume left-to-right evaluation.