# change of variable value in for loop is not updated in original variable

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, variables

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
int main()
{
   ll n,k;
   int count=0;
   cin>>n>>k;
   for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
   {
       if(n%10!=0){
           n=n--;
       }
       else {
           n=n/10;
       }
   }
   cout<<n<<endl;
}
```

value of n isn't changing after performing decrement operation inside for loop

Comment: not sure whats a good duplicate. This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179965/pre-vs-post-increment. You want `n--;` not `n = n--;`

Comment: `n=n--` is undefined behaviour. Aside: competitive programming reinforces bad habits that you will need to forget once you do any real programming. Never use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` or `using namespace std;` or `#define ll long long int`. Always use [`-Wall -Werror`](https://godbolt.org/z/b5f1EcTxb)

Comment: Decrement *or* assign - don't try to do both. Choose between `n--`, `--n`, `n -= 1`, and `n = n - 1`. (And do read about what they all mean.)

Comment: This is terrible idea `#define ll long long int` especially when you can easily replace it with proper `typedef` or using directive

Answer (score 3):

While you decrease `n` with `n--`, you assign it back by

```
n = n--;
```

Just `n--;` is enough (cleaned-up code):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long n,k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (n % 10 != 0) { n--; }
        else { n /= 10; }
    }
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

Input : `15 6`

Output : `1`

As usual, assigning and incrementing/decrementing should be done separately, or [it **will** lead to `undefined behavior`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior). `n -= 1`, `n = n-1` or `--n` will also do the job.

Also see

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
- [Pre vs Post Increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179965/pre-vs-post-increment)

Comment: @UjjwalBhardwaj If it works, please marked one of the answers as correct, so other users searching for this will know what work.

Comment: @Slava sorry, I've rewritten it to remove other bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are decrementing the value of N, but assigning it the old value. Replace:

```cpp
n=n--;
```

with:

```cpp
n--;
```

Comment: "You are decrementing the value of N, but assigning it the old value." this is not quite correct statement